# Rails w/ Devise, Confirmation token not working on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I have a rails app using Devise with confirmable emails. The emails are sending fine, and the confirmation link is working perfectly in development. But in production on Heroku, it doesn't work at all.

Again, the emails send fine on production, the token is generated, but when clicked, the page just redirects to the 'resend confirmation instructions' page. Is there something missing for production to make this work? Any suggestions or help?

Here's my logs from development:

```
Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=SusKNC1PyZ4ayJxL9asR" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 21:32:02 -0400
Processing by Devise::ConfirmationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"confirmation_token"=>"SusKNC1PyZ4ayJxL9asR"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = '28535b0ce6b4cb809463749ccad8ae0c8e92f6e7ce6ea2b9262dc6be87eb1fff'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "confirmation_token" = $1, "confirmed_at" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = 3  [["confirmation_token", nil], ["confirmed_at", "2014-07-14 01:32:02.960080"], ["updated_at", "2014-07-14 01:32:02.960674"]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

and here is my logs from Heroku

```
2014-07-14T01:36:05.606623+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/confirmation" host=www.———.— request_id=76de591e-0948-4b89-93b1-eeb9431b2b9c fwd="72.229.255.68" dyno=web.1 connect=2 service=18 status=304 bytes=1218
2014-07-14T01:36:05.585691+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/confirmation" for 72.229.255.68 at 2014-07-14 01:36:05 +0000
2014-07-14T01:36:05.594512+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.haml (0.5ms)
2014-07-14T01:36:05.594570+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/confirmations/new.html.haml within layouts/application (3.1ms)
2014-07-14T01:36:05.596841+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.haml (1.1ms)
2014-07-14T01:36:05.588617+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::ConfirmationsController#show as HTML
2014-07-14T01:36:05.597479+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 6.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so dumb, just fixed this after I submitted. The problem was with my url. I entered the root domain in my production.rb file for the smtp settings. But I actually have a www url that the root domain redirects too. Ugh

Comment: hi scott, please can you expand a bit more on your solution

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of error: "Confirmation cannot be blank" on production, even though it works on my local machine.  For me the problem was the free account of WWWhisper does not permit unauthorized access and treats the email confirmation link as unauthorized.

Comment: this is what did it for me.